# how to resolve firebase $waitForAuth() .then do something

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

In my app i want to resolve a few things before the front page loads. on my other pages its easy for me as i use this function in my resolve:

```
userAccount.$inject = ['userService','authService'];
function userAccount(userService, authService) {
  return authService.firebaseAuthObject.$requireAuth()
    .then(function(response) {
      return userService.getAccount(response.uid).$loaded();
    });
}
```

And it requires Authorisation, once promise is returned it gets the user data in firebase i saved elsewere. And if the promise is revoked it wont load that page.

But on the home page i want to check if user is logged in, If the user is logged in, grab the users data and goto the page. BUT if the user is not logged in, still go to the page just the user data will be empty.

I currently am using this to check Auth:

```
checkAuth.$inject = ['userService', 'authService'];
function checkAuth(userService, authService) {
  return authService.firebaseAuthObject.$waitForAuth()
}
```

Which works good, but i still want to resolve the users data before loading the page only IF the user is logged in.

I assumed that this was my answer:

```
checkAuth.$inject = ['userService','authService'];
function checkAuth(userService, authService) {
  return authService.firebaseAuthObject.$waitForAuth()
    .then(function(response) {
      return checkAuth.getAccount(response.uid).$loaded();
    });
}
```

Which would wait for the promise then load in the users data, but unfortunately this doesnt work.

Any ideas on how i can retrieve the users data once the $waitforauth() function has run, the key is i want to resolve this data before the page loads.

Thanks guys

my state that also doesnt work:

```
    .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl as vm',
    resolve: {
      checkAuth: checkAuth,
      userAccount: function(checkAuth){
        console.log(checkAuth);
        if(checkAuth){
          // grab user data
        } else {
          return false;
        }

      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Reference to the correct usage of $waitForAuth(): https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-routes

Answer (score 2):

This got it done for me.

State:

```
  .state('main', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl as vm',
    resolve: {
      userAccount: userAccountMain
    }
  })
```

Function:

```
userAccountMain.$inject = ['userService', 'authService'];
function userAccountMain(userService, authService) {
  return authService.firebaseAuthObject.$waitForAuth()
    .then(function(response){
      if(response){
        return userService.getAccount(response.uid).$loaded();
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
}
```